# How to call function in ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call a jQuery function on postback (C#) using scriptmanager.

When I type the function in the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock it works but if I call the function, it doesn't.

Here is my code.

**This code works**:

```
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "MyFun1", "$(document).ready(function () {$('#header2a').fadeIn(5000); });", true);
 }
 </script>
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "MyFun1",   "myFunction();", true);
 }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
function myFunction() {    
$('#header2a').fadeIn(5000);
}
});
</script>
```

Could anyone please point me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Move `myFunction()` declaration out of the `document.onready` event.

Comment: Thanks so much, Malk! That's what I am doing wrong. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work....

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "MyFun1", "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction(parameters);</script>", true);
```

also..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {    
    $('#header2a').fadeIn(5000);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
});
</script>
```